# org.json.JSONException: Value at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android

I have values of the states and cities of India stored in JSON. That code will be to big to put up in here so I tried the same thing but with only states. But that file is not getting compiled.

Error Message :

```
2020-08-14 19:06:02.754 10347-10347/com.luv.foodforhunger W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [{
        "State Name": "Andaman & Nicobar Islands"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Andhra Pradesh"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Arunachal Pradesh"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Assam"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Bihar"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Chandigarh"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Chattisgarh"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Dadra and Nagar Haveli and Daman and Diu"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Delhi"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Goa"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Gujarat"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Haryana"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Himachal Pradesh"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Jammu & Kashmir"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Jharkhand"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Karnataka"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Kerala"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Lakshadweep"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Madhya Pradesh"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Maharashtra"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Manipur"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Meghalaya"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Mizoram"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Nagaland"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Odisha"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Pondicherry"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Punjab"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Rajasthan"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Sikkim"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Tamil Nadu"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Telangana"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Tripura"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Uttar Pradesh"
    }, {
        "State Name": "Uttarakhand"
    }, {
        "State Name": "West Bengal"
    }
]at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

JSON Code :

```
[[{
            "State Name": "Andaman & Nicobar Islands"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Andhra Pradesh"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Arunachal Pradesh"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Assam"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Bihar"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Chandigarh"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Chattisgarh"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Dadra and Nagar Haveli and Daman and Diu"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Delhi"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Goa"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Gujarat"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Haryana"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Himachal Pradesh"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Jammu & Kashmir"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Jharkhand"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Karnataka"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Kerala"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Lakshadweep"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Madhya Pradesh"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Maharashtra"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Manipur"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Meghalaya"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Mizoram"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Nagaland"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Odisha"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Pondicherry"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Punjab"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Rajasthan"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Sikkim"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Tamil Nadu"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Telangana"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Tripura"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Uttar Pradesh"
        }, {
            "State Name": "Uttarakhand"
        }, {
            "State Name": "West Bengal"
        }
    ]]
```

DonorAdressSetUpActivity.java

```java
    public class DonorAdressSetUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    EditText flatNoEditText, buildingNameEditText, streetAndSectorEditText, cityEditText, pinCodeEditText;
    Spinner stateTV;
    String url = "http://luvbarnwal.in/states_of_india.html";
    ArrayList<String> states;

    private void loadSpinnerData(String url) {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String state = jsonObject.getString("State Name");
                        states.add(state);
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(DonorAdressSetUpActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states);
                    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    stateTV.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        int socketTimeout = 30000;
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public void continuee(View view){

        if (flatNoEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            flatNoEditText.setHint("Enter Your Flat Number");
        } else if (buildingNameEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            buildingNameEditText.setHint("Enter Your Building Name");
        } else if (streetAndSectorEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            streetAndSectorEditText.setHint("Enter Your Street & Sector Name");
        } else if (cityEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            cityEditText.setHint("Enter Your City");
        } else if (pinCodeEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            pinCodeEditText.setHint("Enter Your Pin Code");
        } else {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("DonorDetails");
            query.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                    for (ParseObject object : objects) {
                        object.put("flatNo", flatNoEditText.getText().toString());
                        object.put("buildingName", buildingNameEditText.getText().toString());
                        object.put("streetAndSectorName", streetAndSectorEditText.getText().toString());
                        object.put("cityName", cityEditText.getText().toString());
                        object.put("pinCode", pinCodeEditText.getText().toString());
                        object.put("stateName", stateTV.getSelectedItem().toString());

                        object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {

                                    ParseQuery<ParseUser> parseQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
                                    parseQuery.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
                                    parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                                            if (e == null){

                                                if (objects.size() > 0){

                                                    for (ParseUser user : objects){
                                                        user.put("stateName", stateTV.getSelectedItem().toString());

                                                        user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                                                if (e == null){

                                                                    Log.i("Successful", "Your address details has been stored");
                                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DonorContactSetUpActivity.class);
                                                                    startActivity(intent);
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                    }

                                                }

                                            } else {
                                                String message = e.getMessage();

                                                if (Objects.requireNonNull(message).toLowerCase().contains("java")) {

                                                    message = e.getMessage().substring(e.getMessage().indexOf(" "));

                                                }
                                                Toast.makeText(DonorAdressSetUpActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    String message = e.getMessage();

                                    if (Objects.requireNonNull(message).toLowerCase().contains("java")) {

                                        message = e.getMessage().substring(e.getMessage().indexOf(" "));

                                    }
                                    Toast.makeText(DonorAdressSetUpActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_donor_adress_set_up);

        setTitle("Enter Your Address");

        flatNoEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.flatNoEditText);
        buildingNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.buildingNameEditText);
        streetAndSectorEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.streetAndSectorEditText);
        cityEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cityEditText);
        pinCodeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pinCodeEditText);
        stateTV = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.stateTV);

        states = new ArrayList<>();
        loadSpinnerData(url);
        stateTV.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    String state = stateTV.getItemAtPosition(stateTV.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(DonorAdressSetUpActivity.this, state, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_donor_adress_set_up.xml

```html
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".DonorAdressSetUpActivity">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="508dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:text="*"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView2" />
    
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/pinCodeEditText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Pin Code"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cityEditText" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="414dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:text="*"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView2" />
    
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/cityEditText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="City"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/streetAndSectorEditText" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="324dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:text="*"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView2" />
    
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/streetAndSectorEditText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Street and Sector"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buildingNameEditText" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:text="*"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView2" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Enter your Address"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/flatNoEditText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Flat No."
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />
    
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/buildingNameEditText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Building Name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/flatNoEditText" />
    
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
                    android:onClick="continuee"
                    android:text="Continue"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/stateTV" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:text="*"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView2" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:text="*"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView2" />
    
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/stateTV"
                    android:layout_width="399dp"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                    android:prompt="@string/state_name"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/pinCodeEditText" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Please help me resolve my problem, because this app is really important to make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jsonArray` is pointing towards incorrect reference. If you check your raw JSON, it's containing an array inside an array.

```
[ // -> Outer JSONArray
  [ // -> Inner JSONArray
    { // -> JSONObject
      "State Name":"Andaman & Nicobar Islands"
    },....
  ]
]
```

**Replace this:**

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
```

**With:**

```
JSONArray outerJSONArray = new JSONArray(response);
JSONArray jsonArray = outerJSONArray.getJSONArray(0)
```

Comment: @l_b Feel free to accept this as an answer if it works for you.